# How to display input data into an iframe instead of a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input, display

I'm a little bit rusty and just started doing html and javascript again. And need some help with this.

How can I make the information display at a targeted iframe instead of having a new window pop up?

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
  DispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=700,height=400')
  message = "<b>Verified: </b>" + document.form1.Ver.value;
  message += "<br><b>Name: </b>" + document.form1.Gname.value;
  message += "<br><b>ID: </b>" + document.form1.Bid.value;
  message += "<br><b>Concern: </b>" + document.form1.Cxissue.value;
  message += "<br><b>Resolution: </b>" + document.form1.Res.value;
  message += "<br><b>Link: </b>" + document.form1.Htx.value + "<br><br><br>";

  DispWin.document.write(message);
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<iframe id="my-frame"></iframe>
<script>
  var myFrame = document.getElementById('my-frame');
  myFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = 'Hello world!';
</script>
```

*I did not create a StackSnippet because StackOverflow blocks this, but you can see a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/c1vzo29h/1/).*

If you really want to use `.write()`, you can do `myFrame.contentDocument.write(...)`, but it's [not used much these days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: I apologize, I guess I wasn't clear enough. Long story short, I'm making a page with multiple iframes, 3 in total, pretty much it's a menu that displays a form that, once completed, I want it to generate a ready to copy/paste request in the 3rd iframe, instead of making a pop-up.

Here are the files.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=11cETl0f63Jy91r8zNKuQnnMnuVEqUKi3

Comment: In your form files, replace `DispWin.document.write(message)` with `window.parent.querySelector('iframe[name="Generate"]').contentDocument.body.innerHTML = message;`. It will access the parent page, find the third iframe, and alter its contents. Keep in mind that it won't work if you try it locally with a URL like `file:///C:/....`, you need to serve it with `http(s)`, using a local server or a remote one